# Is it legal to include verbatim exercises from a book in videos/on a blog?

Tags: united-states, copyright

I live in Florida, U.S. I recently purchased a math book that I really like, and I am thinking about making a video series or a blog where I would succcessively resolve the exercises from the book.

Of course, to do so, I would have to  reproduce the problem statements in their entirety. Is this a problem?

I am aware of another question on this site which asks the same thing, except it is about translations of Greek manuscripts. However, I think my case is a little differet, for at least one reason: I am not sure how many of the problems are really the author's original work; in math, there are some very "classic" problems that are given by many authors; also, some problems are very fundamental to the theory, and were surely considered by people who first came up with the theory. Additionally, math books are notorious for not citing where they got their problems from, so again one really cannot be sure which, if any, are the author's truly original work.

Comment: Can you word the problems in a very different manner than the book uses? Copyright protects the specific expression of an idea, not the idea itself.  Also, if wording is not original to author A because it was stolen it from author B, you still can't use the wording without the ok of author B.

Comment: Are the problems you plan to reproduce and solve creative expressions? For example I doubt a problem such as "123 + 784 = ?" is a creative expression. However if you write or explain how to carry out additions, carries, and so on, in order to solve that problem, that explanation is your creative expression.